# How to make Valgrind log all allocations?

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I'd like to make Valgrind log the allocations even when no memory errors were found. How can this be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would use [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) for that (a valgrind tool). The manual link is easy enough to follow, but for future reference, here's how to use it, straight out of the manual:

```
valgrind --tool=massif prog
```

This will produce a file that you can analyze with `ms_print`. The filename will be `massif.out.<numbers>`. Just use `ms_print` to get a nice output:

```
ms_print massif.out.12345
```

What you're looking for can be found in the end of the output of `ms_print`. For this example program (the program they show in the manual):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void g(void)
{
    malloc(4000);
}

void f(void)
{
    malloc(2000);
        g();
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int* a[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(1000);
    }

    f();

    g();

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        free(a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

We can see who allocated what:

```
->79.81% (8,000B) 0x400589: g (in /home/filipe/dev/a.out)
| ->39.90% (4,000B) 0x40059E: f (in /home/filipe/dev/a.out)
| | ->39.90% (4,000B) 0x4005D7: main (in /home/filipe/dev/a.out)
| |   
| ->39.90% (4,000B) 0x4005DC: main (in /home/filipe/dev/a.out)
|   
->19.95% (2,000B) 0x400599: f (in /home/filipe/dev/a.out)
| ->19.95% (2,000B) 0x4005D7: main (in /home/filipe/dev/a.out)
|   
->00.00% (0B) in 1+ places, all below ms_print's threshold (01.00%)
```